# Access 2016 Auto Increase Number then Reset to 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

First I apologize for any mistakes. I'm new to VBA.

I have a table (tblCustomers) with 3 fields that need to work together. The fields are JumpDate, Load, and Slot.

I am trying to have the Load and Slot increase from 1 to 12 as the orders are taken.
So If the JumpDate is equal to what is entered and Load is equal to what is entered then Slot +1 of last record with same date and Load up to 12 then resets to 1. Once the Slot reaches 12 then Load should increase by 1 up to 12. If both Load and Slot = 12 then message "All Loads Filled"

I am sure there is a way to do this I'm just not sure how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Maybe you have the wrong idea, about this site. Here, programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post & share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Recommended reading: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Sure there is a way - write code behind a form. Use AfterUpdate event of JumpDate that does a lookup for last values in table and increments and sets value into fields of current record.